# window.ScrollTo(x, y) not working when searching for an element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I've got a document that contains certain elements with unique `ids`. This page contains what could be hundreds of different divs, each with their unique id. For example, consider the following:

```
<div id='root'>
    <div id='my-1-id'>1</div>
    <div id='my-2-id'>2</div>
    <div id='my-3-id'>3</div>
    <div id='my-4-id'>4</div>
    <div id='my-5-id'>5</div>

    // Even more divs

    <div id='my-1000-id'>1000</div>
</div>
```

Within my `React` component, I've implemented a `LazyRendering` feature so that the `document` gets loaded as the user scrolls down the page (which is pretty custom behavior).

However, right now, I'm looking to implement a feature that looks through certain parts of the page using `document.getElementById`. But finding everything on the page isn't working because the full document isn't being rendered in one go. So if the user is on the top of the page and uses this functionality to look for something on the bottom of the page (i.e. the part that hasn't been 'lazy rendered'), then `document.getElementById` will return null.

As a result of all this, I'm looking to implement a function that will simply loop over the document to search for this element. As an example:

```
const lookForElement = (id) => {
    let element = document.getElementById(id)
    while (!element) {
        window.ScrollTo(0, 200) //NOT scrolling
        element = document.getElementById(id)
    }
    return element
}
```

As you can see, if the element is not found, continue scrolling by 200 pixels in height until you find the element. However `window.ScrollTo(0, 200)` isn't working and the page is always fixated at the original height of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to give the DOM time to react. Use a timeout or interval

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you mean setting a timeout when looking for the element? The problem I can see is that the scroll isn't even happening to begin with. So even if I `setTimeout(() => {element = document.getElementById(id)}, 500)` for example, the height of the window remains constant. So I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. it is scrollBy
2. You need to give the DOM some time to react

```js
let testCounter = 0,
id2look4 = ""
const lookForElement = (id) => {
    if (testCounter++ > 3) { // mocking the existance of the div we look for
      document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += `<div id="${id2look4}">ID to look for</div>`
    }

    let element = document.getElementById(id2look4)
    if (element) {
      alert("found")
      element.scrollIntoView()
      return 
    }  
    window.scrollBy(0,200) 
    
    setTimeout(lookForElement,100)
}
id2look4 = "my-1000-id";
lookForElement()
```

```css
div { height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id='root'>
    <div id='my-1-id'>1</div>
    <div id='my-2-id'>2</div>
    <div id='my-3-id'>3</div>
    <div id='my-4-id'>4</div>
    <div id='my-5-id'>5</div>

    // Even more divs

    <div id='my-1500-id'>5</div>
</div>
```

Remove this when tested

```
    if (testCounter++ > 3) {
      document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += `<div id="${id2look4}">ID to look for</div>`
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I've implemented the same function, but for some reason, I'm not getting the scroll to work even by using `scrollBy(x, y)`. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Hard to tell without example data. Perhaps the scroll is not triggering the lazy loading?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I'm trying to replicate my code as much as possible to demonstrate. In the meanwhile, how can I verify in your example that the scroll is actually scrolling? I've tried to `console.log(window.innerHeight)` but I guess that's always going to be the height of the window. How can I get where we are on the page? I guess from your example, we can't really know whether there is an actual scroll or not correct? Because in any case, when `testCounter` reaches 4, you're always going to be able to scroll into the view because you're adding the `<div>` to the DOM.

Comment: You need of course to not have my testcounter script in your page and my script should scroll your page forever if there is no div with the id you want